# Firebase Cloud Messaging set up but not receiving push notifications from Firebase console

Tags: firebase, swift3, xcode8, firebase-cloud-messaging

I've been trying to debug Firebase push notifications for quite a long time now, and got no luck. I believe I have set up provisional profiles and APNs certificate correctly. When I do not include the method

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication,      didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {        
    FIRInstanceID.instanceID().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: .unknown)}
```

App receives notifications in foreground when sent from Firebase Notification console because it gets printed out, but it does not receive notification in background.

If I add the above method to it, it does not receive notification in foreground and background.

Anyone knows what is wrong?

I have already enabled push notifications, remote notifications, and I have setup the APNs certificate correctly. I have also tried reinstalling the app but it does not work. I have also tried all the stackoverflow posts already regarding this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The code snippet that you've provided is for [manual mapping of APNS token with the device registration token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client#token-swizzle-disabled). Basically, you need to explicitly add this when the swizzling is disabled for your app.

Make sure to use the right token type: `FIRInstanceIDAPNSTokenTypeSandbox` for the sandbox environment, or `FIRInstanceIDAPNSTokenTypeProd` for the production environment. If you don't set the correct type, messages are not delivered to your app.

In addition, make sure that the priority is set to **High** in the **Advanced options** section when creating a new message in the Firebase Notification console.

If you're using a [data message type](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#data_messages) to send notification to the client apps via FCM, then it is an intended behavior.

```
{
   "to" : "bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1...",
      "data" : {
      "Nick" : "Mario",
      "body" : "great match!",
      "Room" : "PortugalVSDenmark"
      },
}
```

Per the Firebase documentation:

> On iOS, FCM stores the message and delivers it only when the app is in the foreground and has established a FCM connection.

Comment: I did set 'FIRInstanceIDAPNSTokenTypeSandbox' however after I set this up, I do not receive anything anymore. I do not receive any notification. Even with using the right token. I tried sandbox, prod, unknown as well.